# Linear Space as a direct sum of 2 subspaces?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V, U,$ and $W$ be three finitely spanned linear spaces over the same field $\mathbb{F}$. Let  $T : V \to U, S : U \to W$ be two linear transformations. Suppose that $S\circ T : V \to W $ is an isomorphism.

Prove that $U=\text{Ker }S\oplus \text{Im }T$.

If $S\circ T $ is isomorphic, then both $S$ and $T$ must also be, and $\text{Ker }S=\text{Ker }T$ because they are both injective. I understand the concept, but cannot successfully implement the strategy to prove this.

Comment: Usage note: "isomorphic" does not mean the same thing as "is an isomorphism".

Comment: It is not true that $S$ and $T$ are necessarily isomorphisms, so your strategy is fundamentally flawed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show that $U = U_1 \oplus U_2$, it suffices to show that $\dim(U_1) + \dim(U_2) = \dim(U)$ and $U_1 \cap U_2 = \{0\}$.  Take $U_1 = \ker S$ and $U_2 = \operatorname{im} T$

---

The first statement is a consequence of the rank-nullity theorem.  In particular, we have
$$
\dim U_1 = \dim \ker S = \dim U - \dim \operatorname{im} S.
$$
Note that $\operatorname{im} S \supset \operatorname{im} S \circ T$, and that we must have $\operatorname{im} S \circ T = W$. So, 
$$
\dim U_1 = \dim U - \dim W
$$ 
On the other hand,
$$
\dim U_2 = \dim \operatorname{im}(T) = \dim V - \dim \ker T.
$$
Note that $S \circ T$ is injective, which means that $T$ is injective, which means that $\dim \ker T = 0$.  So, we have $\dim U_1 = \dim V$.  Finally, because $S \circ T$ is an isomorphism, we have $\dim V = \dim W$.  We then have
$$
\dim U_1 + \dim U_2 = \dim U - \dim W + \dim W = \dim U
$$
as was desired.

---

For the second statement: suppose that $x \in U_1 \cap U_2$.  That is, we have $Sx = 0$, and $x = Tv$ for some $v \in V$.  Combining these two statements, we have
$$
0 = Sx = S(Tv) = (S \circ T)v.
$$
Because $S \circ T$ is an injective, $(S \circ T)v = 0$ implies that $v = 0$. This in turn implies that $x = Tv = T(0) = 0$.  So indeed, $U_1 \cap U_2 = \{0\}$.

---

**Alternative proof:**

Since $S \circ T$ is an isomorphism, it is invertible.  Defining $R = (S \circ T)^{-1} \circ S$, we find that $R:U \to V$ and $T: V \to U$ are maps satisfying $R \circ T = \operatorname{id}_V$.

Now, it suffices to note the following.

- $\operatorname{im}(T) \cap \ker (R) = \{0\}$, using the proof from above.
- For any vector $u$, $[u - T(R(u))] \in \ker R$, $T(R(u)) \in \operatorname{im}(T)$, and
  $$ 
  u = [u - T(R(u))] + T(R(u)).
  $$

Since $\ker R = \ker S$, this completes the proof.

It is notable that $\operatorname{im}(T)$ is the eigenspace of $T \circ R$ associated with $\lambda = 1$, and $\ker R$ is the eigenspace of $T \circ R$ associated with $\lambda = 0$.